# Регулярное выражение для определенного типа чисел

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть маска для числа А BBBBB A. Для данной маски написал регулярное выражение

```
/([0-9])\1{0}([0-9])\2{4}([0-9])\3{0}/
```

Но в результате получается, что, например, число 2555553 тоже подходит под эту маску (как и, например, 5555552). Насколько я понял, я некорректно понимаю принцип работы группировки.
Можно ли описать данную маску одним регулярным выражением или придется добавить костыль (первая и последняя цифры равны и нет повторов более 5 раз)?

Comment: `/([0-9])\1{0}([0-9])\2{4}\1{1}/`

Comment: @Yaant, все одинаковые тоже попадают под эту регулярку (A != B)

Comment: В тексте вопроса нигде не было упомянуто, что A должно быть не равно B. Поэтому наличие такого требования даже не пришло в голову. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var n = prompt('Введите симметричное число', 1888881);
if (n.match(/^(\d)(?!\1)(\d)\2{0,4}\1$/)) {
  console.log('подходит');
} else {
  console.log('неа');
}
```

`^` - начало строки
`(\d)` - первая цифра
`(?!\1)` - следующий символ не совпадает с первой цифрой
`(\d)` - вторая цифра
`\2{0,4}` - за ней еще от 0 до 4 таких же цифр
`\1` - и снова первая цифра
`$` - конец строки

Comment: Спасибо. А если бы мне потребовалось так, чтобы первое число отличалось от последнего?

Comment: `\1$` замените на `(?!\1)\d$`